# Algorithm to find set of numbers of a given array with a condition

Tags: java, c, algorithm

Given an integer array of size N by the user.
Print all the possible sets such that sum of all possible numbers equate to a number in the array.

Example:

Array A[]= {1,2,3,4,5}

1+2=3..Output:1,2,3

1+3=4..Output:1,3,4

1+4=5..Output:1,4,5

Initial Design:

1. Take a number and set it to SetSum
2. Generate all sums excluding the selected number; checking that the formulated sum is same as the SetSum
3. Print out the numbers that satisfies the conditions above.
4. Iterate over the array and set the next number as SetSum

A much efficient Design/Implementation or different approach are welcome..

Comment: if they ask you this question then do not work for them.

Comment: A **permutation** of a set is an arrangement of that set in some particular order. (1,2) and (2,1) are permutations of {1,2}. It's hard to tell what are you asked to find, but these are definitely not permutations.

Comment: Yes..I accept..I am interested in only finding the set of numbers that satisfies the given condition..

Comment: I think that this problem is similar to [Subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem), which is NP-complete. And your approach is ok. Additionally you can sort the array, and pass the numbers in front of the `SetSum` number. This will reduce some useless calls to the function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem requires you to find the subsets whose sum totals to a given number(here an element of the set). There are 2 approcahes to doing this:

1. A brute force algorithm where you generate all the subsets manually and sum them all up which is of exponential order of growth (2^n combinations) or
2. Use a dynamic programming approach to the problem and find the sum in polynomial time. This is a standard problem in algorithmics called the subset sum problem. If you are not familiar with the concept of dynamic programming, you can look up any algorithms text book. If you understand dynamic programming, then google for the subset sum problem. Hope that helps!

Comment: As I understand, subset sum problem has a single target K and you can print out all the numbers that sum to K. But over here you have multiple targets..

Comment: Use an 'OR' clause. Instead of checking if the sum has reached a particular integer, check if the sum has reached  (S1|S2| ... | Sn) where S1 to Sn are elements of your set. The other way would be run the algorithm for each of the elements of the set.